# javascript promise not async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, promise

I want to only resolve and return promise once an http get request is set to a few conditions.

```
var getPromise = function(url) {
    // Return a new promise.
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // Do the usual XHR stuff
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', url, true);

        req.onload = function() {
            // This is called even on 404 etc
            // so check the status
            if (req.status == 200) {
                console.log(req);
                if (req.response === '"1"') {
                    // Resolve the promise with the response text
                    resolve(req.response);
                    console.log(req.response);
                }
            } else {
                // Otherwise reject with the status text
                // which will hopefully be a meaningful error
                reject(Error(req.statusText));
                console.log(Error(req.statusText));
            }
        };

        // Handle network errors
        req.onerror = function() {
            reject(Error("Network Error"));
        };

        // Make the request
        req.send();
    });
}

window.promise = getPromise(url);
window.promise.then(function(response) {
    // Execute code after agent leg is connected
    console.log("Connected!!!!!");
}, function(error) {
    console.error("Failed!", error);
});
```

The problem I am having is that the HTTP get request only resolves 1 time and sets the promise to a pending state. in order to see the changed state i need to run this code again in the console. 
It was my understanding that setting req.open(,,true) would make this async.
I want it to only set the promise object when req.response = '"1"'

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean, "*only resolves 1 time and sets the promise to a pending state*"? Once you fulfill a promise it is no more pending.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  A promise will only ever resolve or reject once and then it's state and value are latched - they will never change.  But you are only doing ONE http request for each call to `getPromise()` so that should not be an issue.

Comment: I do see an issue where you don't resolve the promise if `req.status == 200`, but `req.response !== '"1"'`.  Then your promise just never gets resolved or rejected.  Are you sure you don't mean `req.response === "1"`?

Comment: FYI, comparing to `'"1"'` also looks like a likely problem.  Does your response contain the double quoted `"1"` exactly like this?

Comment: Yes, I need to check for exactly '"1"'. thats how it comes back to me. So the http request come back but never gets called again. I need some sort of $broadcast to act as a listener for a change in that req.response === '"1"'

Comment: A promise represents a value. It resolves once - if you need something that changes state several times don't use a promise - although in your case of getting a URL it seems appropriate, recycling a promise is probably not a good idea (but retry is ok) (also, what jfriend00 point out is likely correct).

Comment: What I'm trying to say is - please describe the desired behavior - what flow do you want for getting from a URL.

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. I don't want to continually call the http request. I wanted the promise to sit and wait for a req.response to change to 1.